# Space the name or make them display better on a bar graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to fix the overlaying of names of the bars on a bar graph using matplotlib, I'm just wondering how to make it readable. I have attached the graph below and beside it are the values and the names the graph is using from a dataset. Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

```
   # Pie Chart for Car Models
    elif chartV == 2:
        carFreq = df['model'].value_counts()
        plt.bar(carFreq.index, carFreq, align='center')
        plt.xticks(carFreq.index)
        plt.show()
```

Comment: [`plt.xticks(carFreq.index, rotation=45)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text)?

Comment: It did the trick thanks